# Как из текущей даты вычесть день?

Tags: datetime, powershell, format

Запускаю в .bat код powershell, так как основной код находится в .bat.

```
powershell -c "[Date]$EndDate = (Get-Date).addDays(-1) | Out-File C:\EndDate.txt"
```

1. Как задать формат, чтобы в выводе был `yyyy-MM-dd`?
2. Почему `Out-File` записывает во вторую строку файла?

**Обновление**

Скорее вопрос будет звучать так: Как из текущей даты вычесть день, преобразовать в формат `yyyy-MM-dd` и вывести в файл

Comment: `Get-Date -UFormat '%Y-%m-%d'` - при вводе своего формата даты, проблема с лишними переносами пропадет

Comment: @unsetName, это я уже понял, но тогда я не смогу вычесть день, так как это уже строка

Comment: Так вычитайте день заранее `(Get-Date).addDays(-1) | Get-Date -Format 'yyyy-MM-dd'`

Comment: @unsetName, то что нужно. Оставьте в ответе. Разные способы в голове перебирал, но не такой. Спасибо

Comment: В следующий раз, не изменяйте вопрос после того, как вам дали ответ. Просто задайте новый вопрос, если поняли, что текущий вопрос сформулирован неверно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно вычитать дату заранее, после через пайплайн устанавливать нужный формат вывода:

```
(Get-Date).addDays(-1) | Get-Date -Format 'yyyy-MM-dd'
```

Для формата можно использовать как `-Format 'yyyy-MM-dd'` так и `-UFormat '%Y-%m-%d'`

Comment: Подскажите, в чём проблема. Всё отлично записал, но когда объявляю `set /p StartDate = ...` и вывожу `echo`, то видно лишь "��2"

Comment: @MaxDown задайте отдельный вопрос по новой проблеме, иначе мы можем просто запутаться в решениях

Comment: @MaxDown, написал комментарий, но вопроса уже не было))) Скорее всего powershell записывает в вашем случае в файл неверный формат для чтения из cmd, попробуйте указать явно кодировку ...`Out-File -Encoding "UTF8"`...

Comment: Это должно исправить проблему для приведенного в том вопросе примера

Comment: Спасибо, я уже посмотрел мануал, поэтому удалил вопрос. `Out-File` = UTF-16LE, а `Add-Content` = UTF-8

Answer (score 1):

Потому что get-date так выводит - пустая строка, дата и еще две пустых строки. Легко проверить в powershell. Про формат [написано в инструкции с примерами](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-date?view=powershell-7.1).